# How to include methods in every class in JAVA, like the include function in php?

Tags: android, button, methods, onclick

I am wondering if there is a way to include a repetitive methods in every class for JAVA..

Here is the scenario:

I have 5 layouts:
main.xml
layout1.xml
layout2.xml
layout3.xml
layout4.xml

I understand that in android you need to have a class for every layout.
So i got 5 different classes.

But in all the layouts, there are 4 radio buttons that using the following codes:

```
public void layout1(View target) {
        // Do stuff
        Intent n1 = new Intent(main.this, layout1.class);
        startActivity(n1);
    }


    public void layout2(View target) {
        Intent n2 = new Intent(main.this, layout2.class);
        startActivity(n2);
    }

    public void layout3(View target) {
        Intent n3 = new Intent(main.this, layout3.class);
        startActivity(n3);
    }

    public void layout4(View target) {
        Intent n4 = new Intent(main.this, layout4.class);
        startActivity(n4);
    }
```

The buttons are assigned by using the 'android:onclick' in the layout. How can I include these methods in every class so that I do not need to copy and paste if I have a lot of classes/layouts?

Because in PHP, you can include functions in every page by using

```
include 'functionfilename.php';
```

how can I do it in Java? Is there a way?

Comment: Read up on inheritance, then design a base class and extend it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make a abstract  class that extends `Activity` class call it `BaseActivity` and then in all your activities extend your `BaseActivity` class instead of Activity directly,

Comment: Thanks! After reading up on abstract class, i am able to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Before attempting anything with Android you should learn Object Oriented techniques and how to apply it with Java.